# JedisCluster : Scan For Key does not work

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I was trying to scan for particular key stored in [JedisCluster](http://static.javadoc.io/redis.clients/jedis/2.9.0/redis/clients/jedis/JedisCluster.html).

```
String product = "MMATest";

String redisServer = "mycachecluster.eaogs8.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379,mycachecluster.eaogs8.0002.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379";
    Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNode = new HashSet<>();
    String[] serversArray = redisServer.split(";");
    for (String aServersArray : serversArray) {
        jedisClusterNode.add(new HostAndPort(aServersArray.split(":")[0],
                Integer.valueOf(aServersArray.split(":")[1])));
    }
    JedisCluster jedisCluster = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNode,
            buildPoolConfig());

ScanParams params = new ScanParams();
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("");
joiner.add("{");
joiner.add("Image-"+product);
joiner.add("}");
params.match(joiner.toString()).count(100);
System.out.println(joiner.toString());
ScanResult<String> scanResult = null;
String scanMarker = "0";
 do {
     scanResult = jedisCluster.scan(ScanParams.SCAN_POINTER_START, params);
      System.out.println(scanResult.getResult());
             System.out.println(!(scanResult.getResult() == null || scanResult.getResult().isEmpty()));

         } while (!scanMarker.equals("0"));

        ScanResult<Map.Entry<String,String>> scan = jedisCluster.hscan(joiner.toString(), ScanParams.SCAN_POINTER_START);
        System.out.println(scan.getResult());
```

Here I was getting the null value. But there is a value stored in the cluster node.

But if I try to scan the each Jedis pool, I will get the result.

```
  Map<String, JedisPool> jedisPools = jedisCluster.getClusterNodes();
         Set<String>jedisPoolList = jedisPools.keySet();
         System.out.println(jedisPools.keySet());
         System.out.println(jedisPools.values());
         System.out.println(jedisPools.size());
         for (String hostAndPort : jedisPoolList) {
             String[] parts = hostAndPort.split(":");
             String host = parts[0];
             int port = Integer.valueOf(parts[1]);
             try (Jedis jedis = new Jedis(host, port)) {
                 ScanParams params = new ScanParams().match("Image-"+product).count(100);
                 String scanMarker = "0";
                 ScanResult<String> results = null;

                 do {
                     results = jedis.scan(scanMarker, params);
                     System.out.println("XXXX"+results.getResult());
                     System.out.println("XXXX"+!(results.getResult() == null || results.getResult().isEmpty()));

                 } while (!scanMarker.equals("0"));
             }
         }
```

Why the JedisCluster scan method does not give the proper result? How do I solve this issue?

Note:  I can use `jedisCluster.exists(key)` to check the key's existence. But I need to use scan as I can use the same interface to both Jedis and JedisCluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 1:**

In your implementation with `Jedis`, you are matching `Image-MMATest`. As you are getting data, it proves that data is stored by that key.

However, with `JedisCluster` implementation, you have enclosed `"Image-"+product` with curly braces. Which means you are actually matching `{Image-MMATest}`. Your are not getting any data, because no data is stored by that key.

**Part 2:**

In JedisCluster, `scan` support is limited to Redis hash tag pattern. `Image-MMATest` is not Redis hash tag compliant pattern. Because of that you won't be able to get `Image-MMATest` using `scan` of JedisCluster.

To get data by `scan` of JedisCluster, you'd have to store data against a key which is Redis hash tag compliant pattern, e.g. `{Image-MMATest}`.

More details about Redis hash tag can be found in [this documentation](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-hash-tags).

Comment: Ok. So I need to store the key in a curly braces?

Comment: Yes, you need to store the key in a curly braces.

Answer (score -1):

Scan works on only a single redis, and does not scan in all nodes in the redis cluster. While scanning, you should always use Jedis instance and not JedisCluster.

So, ideally for scanning all keys of a particular pattern in a redis cluster, you should do the following.

```
for <Ip:port> in List<Ip:port> {
      Connect to Redis using Jedis and get Jedis object.
      scan using Jedis.
      do stuff with result.
}
```

Comment: I have already mentioned your answer in my question. If you go through Java Api there is a method called scan for jedisCluster. If it is provided means it should work somehow. But it is not in my case.