# How to search the keyspace in Redis using JEDISCLUSTER client?

Tags: redis, jedis

I am storing Map in a keyspace in REDIS. I have stored multiple Map in multiple keyspace as shown in the code. Now I want to search the keyspace using wildcard. Is it possible, if yes how to do that?

```
package kafka;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster;
import redis.clients.jedis.ScanParams;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JedisCluster connection = JedisConnection.getInstance().getconnection();

    Map<String, String> ks = new HashMap<>();
    ks.put("one", "one");
    ks.put("two", "two");
    ks.put("four", "four");
    connection.hmset("parent_child1", ks);

    Map<String, String> ks1 = new HashMap<>();
    ks1.put("one", "one1");
    ks1.put("two", "two1");
    ks1.put("three", "three");
    connection.hmset("parent_child2", ks1);

    Map<String, String> ks2 = new HashMap<>();
    ks2.put("one", "one2");
    ks2.put("two", "two1");
    ks2.put("three", "three3");
    connection.hmset("parent_child3", ks2);

    Map<String, String> ks3 = new HashMap<>();
    ks3.put("one", "one3");
    ks3.put("two", "two3");
    ks3.put("three", "three3");
    connection.hmset("parent_child1", ks3);

    System.out.println(connection.hkeys("parent_child1"));
    //Output : [two, three, four, one]
    connection.hscan("parent_*", "0", new ScanParams().match("{parent_}"));
    connection.hscan("parent_*", "0");
    System.out.println(connection.hgetAll("parent_child1"));
    //Output: {two=two3, three=three3, four=four, one=one3}


}
}
```

Now I want to search the keyspace using **parent_*** so that it give me all keyspace name starting with **parent_** i.e. parent_child1, parent_child2, parent_child3.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [JedisCluster : Scan For Key does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732535/jediscluster-scan-for-key-does-not-work)

You have to iterate through all your nodes and search for the keys like below.

```
Set<byte[]> keys = new HashSet<>();
Map<String, JedisPool> nodes = connection.getClusterNodes();
for(String key : nodes.keySet()) {
  JedisPool jedisPool = nodes.get(key);
  Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
  keys.addAll(connection.keys("parent_*"));
  jedis.close();
}
```

Comment: Above code results in an exception.


**Reids Cluster Initialization Process starting...
Redis cluster Initialization Process END
PSS>>>[attr13, attr12, attr11]
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
 at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53)
 at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226)
 at kafka.RedisExample.main(RedisExample.java:39)**